# jquery datepicker not working on dynamically added table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This is the javascript code to add table row dynamically.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $(document).on("click", ".classAdd", function () { 
             var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person').length + 1;
             var MyDiv = '<tr>' +
                 '<td style="width:6%; padding-left:10px;"><input type="text" name="DateS' + rowCount + '" class="form-control pull-left DateR"/></td>' +
                 '<td style="width:35%; padding-left:5px;"><input type="text" name="STA' + rowCount + '" class="form-control l-name01" style="width:98%"/></td>' +
                 '<td style="width:18%"><input type="text" name="CB' + rowCount + '" class="form-control email01" style="width:98%"/></td>' +
                 '<td style="width:20%"><input type="text" name="Venue' + rowCount + '" class="form-control email01" style="width:98%"/></td>' +
                 '<td style="width:20%"><button type="button" id="btnDelete" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button></td>' +
                 '</tr>';

             $('#Mytable').append(MyDiv); 

         });
     });
</script>
```

And this is for my datepicker. This is located below of my content page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.DateR').datepicker({
    autoclose: true
});
</script>
```

I have no problem adding table row, My problem is on the added row, jQuery Datepicker is not working.

Comment: You need to apply `.datepicker({
    autoclose: true
})` for new controls

Comment: as Satpal said, rerun the initialization code and it should appear.

Comment: @Satpal, How I will apply the datepcker for the new control?

Comment: after `$('#Mytable').append(MyDiv);` just add one more line `$('.DateR').datepicker({ autoclose: true});`

Comment: @vijayP, I already try that approach, but its not working.

Comment: try adding `setTimeout` there to allow new HTML to get rendered correctly before re-initing the datepicker like `setTimeout(function(){('.DateR').datepicker({ autoclose: true});},10)`